# How can i iterate in C a string by word

Tags: c, loops, find

I need to make a program which takes as input on text file and output the same string with one replaced word; the main function will take 3 parameters (wordR, wordS, file). So can anyone help me with a good tip how I can scan the words in c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with strtok() or strtok_r() function.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious possibility would be `[fs]scanf`'s "%s" conversion:

```
char one_word[64];

fscanf(input_file, "%63s", one_word);
```